# How to ignore time and/or date difference between the client and server while fetching the file details?

Tags: c#, windows

Currently, I am working on automating a windows service and stuck with an issue. My test script can run anytime and modifies the machine time zone and time successfully (using `TZUTIL` and `TIME` commands) to 10 AM UTC on a remote machine

But when I try to get the files from any drive from the remote machine, I get `System.IO.IOException: There is a time and/or date difference between the client and server`

I have tried below: (Used same accounts on both machines and account is admin as well)

1. Tried to Start/Stop the Windows Time (service - W32Time)
2. Tried to sync both TZ and Time on both the machine where the script is triggered and the script is running.
3. Used `NET TIME /DOMAIN:XXXX /SET /Y`
4. Used `W32Time /resync`

I tried to [this](http://www.computerstepbystep.com/windows_time_service.html) link as well. But none worked.

I am wondering is there a way to get rid of this issue like I want to ignore this issue and continue with my test execution or am I missing anything here.

Please let me know if you need any other details. Thanks.

**EDIT:**

Blunder. I did a mistake. While updating time TZ and Time I was using the IP address and while getting the files from the directory, I was using the machine name. Seems to issues with machine name. When I changed its IP address, everything started working.

Comment: Why you need to change time and zone on remote machine?

Comment: As part of windows service, there will be a file created during 10-11 AM UTC service run. I want to test (some times) not in 10-11AM time, so I am updating the time.

Comment: Blunder. I did a mistake. While updating time `TZ` and `Time` I was using the IP address and while getting the files from the directory, I was using the machine name. Seems to issues with machine name. When I changed its IP address, everything started working.